# compile Typescript in Azure devops

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a pipeline to compile Typescript files (.ts) that are in a folder.
I created a classic pipeline that so far installs *npm*.
What do I need to do next?
I assume I need to install *tsc*, but I do not know how to do that or what follows next.
Is this possible to do in DevOps? If so, how?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [**Microsoft-hosted agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) to run the pipeline, on some of the MS hosted agents, **`tsc`** has been pre-installed.

If you use [**Self-hosted agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), ensure you have manually installed **`tsc`** on the agent machine.

If you are not sure whether the agent machine has **`tsc`** installed, you can run the "**`npm install -g typescript`**" command line to install the latest **`tsc`**.

After above steps, you can use **`tsc`** command to compile your Typescript files (.ts) in Azure Pipelines.

Below is an example as reference:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Compile TypeScript'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2022
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Check TypeScript version'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "Install TypeScript:"
        npm install -g typescript
        echo "Check TypeScript version:"
        tsc --version

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Compile TypeScript'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "Compile TypeScript file:"
        tsc example.ts
```